# .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewriteRule (with no luck) that would take the string after the hash and rewrite it as a querystring parameter. Something like this...

`http://www.example.com/locations/new-york#7F1A6245-3BE3-62D5-A4B6-60C5D599BF21`

and rewrite to this...

`http://www.example.com/locations/details.aspx?id=7F1A6245-3BE3-62D5-A4B6-60C5D599BF21`

I'm using iis7 with .htaccess file, so I'm pretty sure it's the same regex that you would use for .htaccess with apache. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Based on Ulrich Palha's answer here's what I did...

`RewriteRule ^/locations/(.*)/(.*)$ /locations/details.aspx\?id=$2 [NC,L,U]`

...and that works like a charm. Thanks Ulrich!

Comment: The hash part is never send to the server. So you'll have to do this on the client side with JS.

Comment: that explains why it hasn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this.  The fragment identifier is not transmitted to the server. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document

Therefore you will not be able to process it on the server side...