# fixing an url using htacces

Tags: .htaccess

here it's my end of link : `.../home#&ui-state=dialog`.  I would fix this link through `htaccess` in this way the link is `/home/info`. How could I do?

Comment: You cannot do this via .htaccess see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477275/htaccess-rewriterule/8477598#8477598, but you could with Javascript

Comment: @UlrichPalha can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load a page based on the url hash (junk preceding #)?

In JQuery, something like:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange',function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == '&ui-state=dialog') {
        window.location.href = '/home/info';
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
});
```